# Живое отображение CardView

Tags: android, изображения, recyclerview, view, cardview

Доброго времени суток. 
Как сделать живое отображение `CardView` в `RecyclerView`? 
Пользователь может создать карточку с изображением и без. Изображение в шаблоне не превышает `120dp`. 
Если пользователь добавляет изображение - проблем нет. Если не добавляет - создаётся пустое пространство в `120dp`, которого, по идеи, не должно быть, только текст и описание. 
Если сделать высоту изображения `wrap_content` , то карточка может быть на весь экран, что недопустимо. 

***Шаблон:***

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/forest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:text="TextView" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

***Как должно быть:*** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если пользователь создаёт `CardView` без изображения, то стоит ставить видимость у `ImageView` равную `View.GONE`, а если с изображением, то `View.VISIBLE`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
    ...
    Item item = items.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setVisibility(item.getImage() == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

А то, что карточка может быть на весь экран - это нормальное поведение, так как `RecyclerView` **переиспользует** `View`, а **не пересоздаёт**. Именно поэтому важно обрабатывать оба варианта условия `item.getImage() == null`, так как если мы обработаем лишь тот момент, когда картинки нет, то `RecyclerView` может взять на переиспользование карточку у которой `ImageView` скрыто, и хоть в `item'e` и присутствует картинка, она не будет показана, так как мы не обработали соответствующий момент условия.

Comment: Ух, спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать так:

```
// в адаптере проверять нужно ли показывать картинку
imageView.setVisibility(item.hasImage() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Вместо item.hasImage() - подставить нужное boolean значение, которое определяет есть картинка для этого CardView или нет.